# How to plot map from geoJSON with tooltip on echarts4r

Tags: r, geojson, echarts4r

I'm trying to plot a map obtained from the [`{chilemapas}` R package](https://github.com/pachadotdev/chilemapas) as a geoJSON file, following this example from the [`{echarts4r}` documentation](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/map#geojson-support)

Import geoJSON file from the {chilemapas} GitHub page:

```
json <- jsonlite::read_json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pachadotdev/chilemapas/master/data_geojson/comunas/r10.geojson")
```

Data for plotting, where each number in the `codigo_comuna` column uniquely identifies each region/polygon from the geoJSON file, and the column `poblacion` contains total population:

```
data <- structure(list(codigo_comuna = c("10101", "10102", "10103", "10104", 
                                         "10105", "10106", "10107", "10108", "10109", "10201", "10202", 
                                         "10203", "10204", "10205", "10206", "10207", "10208", "10209", 
                                         "10210", "10301", "10302", "10303", "10304", "10305", "10306", 
                                         "10307", "10401", "10402", "10403", "10404"), 
                       poblacion = c(245902, 
                                     33985, 4023, 12261, 18428, 17068, 17591, 14216, 44578, 43807, 
                                     38991, 14858, 3829, 13762, 3921, 5385, 27192, 8352, 8088, 161460, 
                                     8999, 20369, 11667, 14085, 7512, 10030, 5071, 2623, 8944, 1711
                       )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 
                                -30L))
```

```
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   codigo_comuna poblacion
#   <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 10101            245902
# 2 10102             33985
# 3 10103              4023
# 4 10104             12261
```

Finally, I create the plot according to the documentation: the map displays correctly, and the legend shows the correct data range, but hovering the cursor over the map highlights the whole map instead of each region within the map, and the tooltip displays nothing. This result is not expected, as the example available in documentation shows a working tooltip and region names on hover.

```
data |> 
  e_charts(codigo_comuna) |>
  e_map_register("chile", json) |>
  e_map(poblacion, map = "chile") |> 
  e_tooltip() |> 
  e_visual_map(poblacion)
```

[image]